# How do I P/Invoke the dnsapi.dll method: DnsValidateServerStatus

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am not all that familiar with unmanaged code but have been using some of the methods in dnsapi.dll in my C# application. There are lots of examples on how to use DnsQuery, or DnsFlushResolverCache for example, but the method DnsValidateServerStatus seems to be new (requiring Win 7 or Server 2008 R2). I would like to use this method from my C# application but I can't seem to get the Marshaling and structures to work correctly. The documentation for this method can be found at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee837436(v=VS.85).aspx

Please help!

Comment: Avoid making this a 'send me teh codez' question, post what you got.

Comment: When you figure this out, consider posting the solution to http://pinvoke.net also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difficult part of this Win32 API is the `SOCKADDR` structure. On [PINVOKE.NET](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/SOCKADDR.html) there is an implementation of the `SOCKADDR` structure. The following example is based on this implementation:

```
[DllImport("Dnsapi.dll")]
private static extern int  DnsValidateServerStatus(IntPtr sockaddr, string queryName, ref uint serverStatus);

WinsockSockAddr addr = new WinsockSockAddr(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 0);
uint serverStatus = 0;
int status = DnsValidateServerStatus(addr.PinnedSockAddr, "fqdn server name", ref serverStatus);

Console.Out.WriteLine(status);
Console.Out.WriteLine(serverStatus);
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: That seems to work for the most part! I get DNS_VALSVR_ERROR_UNREACHABLE and DNS_VALSVR_ERROR_NO_RESPONSE per the API when the server is not available. I get DNS_VALSVR_ERROR_NO_AUTH when the server is operational, not sure why I'm not getting the success method. Maybe I'm using the queryName wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure does it work:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct sockaddr {

    /// u_short->unsigned short
    public ushort sa_family;

    /// char[14]
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=14)]
    public byte[] sa_data;
}



    /// Return Type: DWORD->unsigned int
    ///server: PSOCKADDR->sockaddr*
    ///queryName: PCWSTR->WCHAR*
    ///serverStatus: PDWORD->DWORD*
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("dnsapi.dll", EntryPoint="DnsValidateServerStatus")]
public static extern  uint DnsValidateServerStatus([System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] ref sockaddr server, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.InAttribute()] [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAsAttribute(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string queryName, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.OutAttribute()] out uint serverStatus) ;
}
```

Comment: This looks similar to what I had been playing with. To test the pinvoke, I would use something like:
public static void Test()
  {
   sockaddr addr = new sockaddr();
   addr.sa_family = 1;
   IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("10.70.72.20");
   addr.sa_data = BitConverter.GetBytes(ip.Address);
   string query = string.Empty;
   uint status = 0;

   uint result = DnsValidateServerStatus(ref addr, query, out status);

  }

In this case, I always get a Marshaling exception due to the fact that the byte array for the IP is not as big as the 14 specified in the struct.

Comment: I removed the SizeConst=14 from the struct and then the pinvoke returns with status=4 every time.

Comment: Try using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.getaddressbytes.aspx to get address bytes.